# Open new ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I writing and IOS app which connects with Google to identify the new user (registrationviewcontroller). So, the app open a  web navigator to complete the identification process. When the identification process finish and return to the app thanks to my own URL scheme I would like to open a new View instead of registrationviewcontroller one.

Firstly, Where is the best places to call the new viewcontroller? In the method applicationDidBecomeActive of the APPdelegate? or in the load method from the Registration ViewController?

Secondly, How can I lunch the new ViewController?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you opening safari or opening the URL in a webview inside the app?

Comment: I'm Opening from Safari.

Comment: Then that would be difficult I guess. You might have to try opening this in a webview and once you get the response you can launch any viewcontroller from there onwards. Once it goes to safari, I am not sure whether you can get any feedback from there to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, the app gets opened via a custom URL scheme. So

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
```

will be called when your app reopens and you can easily present a view controller there, e.g..:

```
SampleViewController *viewController=[[SampleViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

BTW: I'd recommend you to show the registrationViewController modally, if you don't already, this way you could simply dismiss it in handleOpenURL an would not need the code in the listing above. e.g.:

```
[SampleSuperViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: You cant call [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES]; because APPDelegate it's not a ViewController.

Comment: I'm sorry. You'll have to use a reference to your root view controller in the app delegate. Try to use self.window.rootViewController